# data types and switch-case statement resolution

Tags: c, types, duplicates, switch-statement

Consider below code(C language) which contains duplicate cases. Compiler does not give any warning/error this time.

```
void testSwitchCase() {
char d = 0;
switch(d) {
  case 'a' + 'b':
       printf("I am case 'a' + 'b'\n");
       break;
  case 'a' + 'b':
       printf("I am case 'a' + 'b' \n");
       break;
    }
}
```

**But if I change** `char d = 0` to `int d = 0`, compiler starts raising an error regarding duplicate cases.

> error: duplicate case value

I understand that the expression `'a' + 'b'` should evaluate to an `int` but my point is that it should raise duplicate case error both the times. Why it doesn't?

Comment: What compiler are you using? have you tried to run this on two different compilers?

Comment: gcc 32 bit. codeblocks-16.01mingw which includes the GCC/G++ compiler. Ok let me try some online compilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is the value of `'a'+'b'` on your system, which is 195 on systems with ASCII encoding. This is above 127, the highest `char` value on systems with *signed* characters. Therefore, the compiler safely ignores both `case` labels.

Since value `195` is within the range for `int`, the compiler can no longer ignore it, so it must issue a duplicate case error.

If you change `'a'+'b'` to `'0'+'1'`, you get `97`, which is within the range of a signed char, you get duplicate case error with `char d` as well:

```
char d = 0;
switch(d) {
case '0' + '1':
   printf("I am case 'a' + 'b'\n");
   break;
case '0' + '1':
   printf("I am case 'a' + 'b' \n");
   break;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/pyo0lt)

Answer (score 1):

Took too long and posted 7 minutes too late :P...

My guess would be the following:
A char variable cannot hold 'a' + 'b', this would cause overflow, i.e. undefined behavior.
But 'a' + 'b' is promoted to an int, due to integer promotion rules. 
char d can never equal this value and the compiler removes these cases entirely. int d can be equal to both cases and the compiler issues the error.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Case Error means you have defined two cases with the same value in the switch statement. You are probably looking at your code thinking "but they are all different." To you they are different. To the compiler they look much different.

You have defined case statements using the character notation.  Single quotes are meant for characters, not strings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP knows all of this. Look at the last paragraph of his question.

Comment: He wants characters. Look at the expression in the switch. And he thinks they are all same but does not get a warning unless he changes d to be an int.

Comment: Your misunderstanding has nothing to do with the switch() construct, it's all about the single quotes '': If you write 1, you get an integer of the value 1, when you put it in single quotes '1', you get the numeric value of the ASCII character for the digit 1 (this is a bit imprecise, see note below). That ASCII character has the numeric value of 0x31, or 49 in decimal. Now imagine the difference.

Comment: Sorry! was disconnected from Net. @dasblinkenlight is correct.